# When regularity implies normality

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a hausdorff topological space. It is well known that if $X$ is  regular and lindelof then it is normal. Is the any other topological property $*$ for $X$ such that "regular+$*\rightarrow$ normal"?

Comment: looking for covering properties?

Comment: Not necessarily a covering property.

Comment: stuff like connectedness properties won't do.

Comment: Normality, for example. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Already Hausdorff plus paracompactness implies normality. (this is in the realm of covering properties), but you cannot go much weaker than that (metacompactness will not do, e.g., see the Dieudonné plank). Outside of covering properties, I cannot think of much.

Answer (score 1):

The Nagata-Smirnov Metrization Theorem: A space is metrizable iff it is regular and has a $\sigma$-locally finite base.

A $\sigma$-locally finite family is a countable union of locally finite families. A locally finite family in a space $X$ is a family $F$ of subsets of $X$ such that each $p\in X$ has a nbhd $U$ such that $\{f\in F: f\cap U\ne \emptyset\}$ is finite.

A  finite family is,obviously, locally finite. A countable family is a countable union of finite families, so it is $\sigma$-locally finite. Hence, by the theorem above:

A second-countable regular space is metrizable, and therefore normal.

Comment: A bit of overkill to deduce the much easier Urysohn metrisation theorem from Bing-Nagata-Smirnov though....

Comment: @HennoBrandsma. True. But the N-S theorem itself is an example of what the OP asked for.

Comment: the result is not just normality (as Lindelöf does), but the much stronger metrisability. N-S is the missing link to being metrisable, not just being normal.